# Elm project scaling: separating Messages/Updates

Tags: elm

I am trying to separate files in an Elm project, as keeping everything in global Model, Messages, etc. would be just a mess.
Here is how I tried it so far:

[image]

So, there are some global files, and then Header has its own files. However I keep getting error, when importing `Header.View` into my global View:

```
The 1st and 2nd entries in this list are different types of values.
```

Which kind of makes sense:

- The 1st entry has this type:

  ```
  Html Header.Messages.Msg
  ```
- But the 2nd is:

  ```
  Html Msg
  ```

So, my question is whether all the messages (from all my modules, like Header) needs to be combined somehow in global `Messages.elm`? Or there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: If you go down this route code will be harder to refactor and the compiler will be slower. Is fine to split the views but consider keeping the messages and model in the root for as long as you can.

Comment: Hey @Sebastian, can you explain why is it better to keep only in root? Lets say I have 50 different components, and it seems to be that one model file would just become to long eventually vs having folder with its files for every component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice would be to keep messages and update in 1 file until that feels uncomfortable (for you to decide how many lines of code that means - see Evan's [Elm Europe talk](https://youtu.be/XpDsk374LDE) for more on the modules flow). When you want to break something out, define a new message in Main

```
type Msg 
    = HeaderMsg Header.Msg 
    | ....
```

Then use `Cmd.map HeaderMsg` in your update function and `Html.map HeaderMsg` in your view function to connect up your sub-components

Comment: or perhaps consider using `Html msg` type signature in the library?

Comment: Hey @Simon, I've accepted your answer, as it helped me to achieve the goal. But can you elaborate a bit or point me in right direction, why is it better to keep in one file?

Comment: It's not 'better' to keep everything in one file, but in Elm you should not feel compelled to break everything in multiple files - see link added to answer